# AWSのS３にphpで画像をアップロード

Tags: php, aws, amazon-s3

以下のようなコードを書いているのですが、画像がS３にアップロードされません。
S３のURLは正常に出力されています。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

```
//画像関連
                $file = date('YmdHis') . $_FILES['top_img']['name'];
                $img_tmp_name = $_FILES['top_img']['tmp_name'];
                move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name, "img/" . $file);

                // Instantiate an Amazon S3 client.
                $s3 = new S3Client([
                    'version' => '2006-03-01',
                    'region'  => 'ap-northeast-1',
                    'credentials' => [
                        'key' => 'key',
                        'secret' => 'secret',
                    ],
                ]);

            try {
                $result = $s3->putObject([
                    'Bucket'       => 'bucket',
                    'Key'          => 'img/'.$file,
                'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
                    'Body'         => fopen('test.php', 'r'),
                'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                ]);

                echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
            } catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
            }
```

Comment: Exceptionのメッセージを追記できますか？質問のコードだとよくわからなかったのですが 指定したバケット名やアクセスキー、シークレットは正しくて、AWS側のアクセス許可も問題ないという認識で合ってますか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません。exceptionのメッセージとはなんでしょうか。
バケット等の項目は全て正しいです。
s3にはファイル名はちゃんと出ているのですが、ファイルの中身が真っ白になっています。。

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ja/exception.getmessage.php ←このように `$e->getMessage()` でエラーメッセージを取り出せないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`putObject` 時に `Body` キーに `fopen('test.php', 'r')` を代入されているのですが、ファイルをアップロードしたい場合、下記のように `SourceFile` キーにアップロードしたいファイルのパスを指定する形になるかと思います。

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => 'bucket',
    'Key'          => 'img/'.$file,
    'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'SourceFile'   => 'img/'.$file,
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
));
```

詳細は、AWSのドキュメントを参照してください。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html